# 'Failed shutdown of Apache Portable Runtime' from Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

After I have deployed and clicked around in an application, tomcat won't shut down gracefully from within the Netbeans IDE.

This is what can be seen in the netbeans/tomcat console after "stop" has been pressed.

```
Sep 27, 2009 11:17:40 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 27, 2009 11:17:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 27, 2009 11:17:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 27, 2009 11:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Failed shutdown of Apache Portable Runtime
```

The progressbar down right in the IDE continues for a minute or two then an error popup is shown with "Stopping of Tomcat failed" and I have to kill the process manually.

This only happens when I'm running from within the IDE, starting and stopping from the console is no problem.

I have no running background threads that I have started from the application, though I use Ehcache (which runs cleanup threads in the background), Spring, Hibernate and JSF.

How can I make tomcat to shutdown gracefully from Netbeans?

Comment: Even am having similar kind of issue, not sure what could be the possible reason for it and what could be a work around for the same.