# What does 'Failed shutdown of Apache Portable Runtime' log message mean?

Tags: tomcat

After shutting down tomcat, I get this message:

```
INFO: Failed shutdown of Apache Portable Runtime
```

Then Tomcat shuts down after all

I haven't found a reasonable explanation googling around, nor in the single [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484557/failed-shutdown-of-apache-portable-runtime-from-netbeans) I've found (0 answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is not due to some daemon threads after all, just a poor log message

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38652

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause is that a non-daemon thread is still running ([Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q25)). Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java) for more information on daemon threads.

To find out which thread is causing problems (on Unix):

- do a `kill -3 tomcatProcId` (find *tomcatProcId* using ps)
- look inside $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out for the thread dump generated by the kill
- look at all the non-daemon threads (those not marked with "daemon") that are not VM/GC related
- for each one, find out what code spawned it, and why it has not terminated correctly. Some non-daemon threads check frequently to terminate, which is OK.

If you want, you can instruct Tomcat to kill the JVM after shutdown, even if non-daemon threads remain (which might sometimes be a [bad thing](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35124)):

- define the CATALINA_PID environment variable. For example: `export CATALINA_PID=/tmp/catalina_pid`
- use `catalina.sh stop -force` to stop Tomcat.

Comment: +1 on a good and thorough answer, but I'm not sure it is the deal, please read my answer as well, and comment if you don't think it resolves my own question

Comment: Good point. I missed the "Then Tomcat shuts down after all" part. Your answer seems to be the correct one in this case, and you should accept it. I hope my answer will still help other people, who might encounter the Daemon Thread problem.